# Hola, necesito realizar el envio de un mail con la info de un formulario con varios datos

Tags: django, django-forms

Este es el form

```
               class EnviosForm(ModelForm):
                   class Meta:
                   model = Envios
                   fields = '__all__'
```

Como lo agrego a mi views??

```
             class Envios(CreateView):
                 model = Envios
                 form_class = EnviosForm
                 template_name = 'Envios.html'
                 success_url = reverse_lazy('Envios')

                def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
                     context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
                     context["title"] = 'Envios'
                     return context
```

Por favor denme una idea para agregarlo
Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: haz intentado hacerlo con Google Forms? queda mucho mas estetico. es solo una sugerencia

Comment: La verdad nunca lo use. Se puede incorporar a mi web hecha con Django??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

una solución sencilla seria sobre-escribir el método form valid de CreateView, como ahí puedes recuperar todo lo que tiene el formulario, puedes enviar esa informaicon con send_mail de Django:

```
    class Envios(CreateView):
        model = Envios
        form_class = EnviosForm
        template_name = 'Envios.html'
        success_url = reverse_lazy('Envios')
        
        def form_valid(self, form):
            """dentro recuperas los valores del form y usas la función 
               send_mail"""

            
            self.object = form.save()
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

Documentación de envió email: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#quick-example